# I'm looking for ideas what kind of application to develop when learning sproutcore

Tags: javascript, sproutcore

do you have ideas what application (more complicated than todo) is good to develop when learning sproutcore?

Answer (score 2):

How about a calculator? lots of buttons and answers, or they can type.

A javascript tester?  Let users add their own javascript, and show the result.

Answer (score 2):

A Tetris clone is always fun. You would be using:

- ArrayControllers, ObjectControllers
- KVO Bindings
- Key Listeners

Answer (score 1):

Writing a blog platform is a nice way to test out a new language/framework.  Got all your CRUD operations plus enough room to add as many bells and whistles as you feel like.